# Click to move - get NavMesh layer

Tags: unity, raycasting, navmesh

I'm using NavMesh, and NavMeshAgent for my character movement and Pathfinding.

I made a testing NavMesh with 2 area layers:

0 = `Walkable`
3 = `Water`.

In have a  click to move script, and i need to get the ID of the NavMesh Area where the player clicked. I tried to get the ID of the layer where the player clicked, using `NavMeshHit.mask` but is always resulting 0, even if I click where the NavMesh area ID is 3.

From Unity [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/NavMeshHit-mask.html):

> Mask specifying NavMesh area at point of hit.

Script:

```
RaycastHit hit;
NavMeshHit nHit;
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)){
    bool hasHit = NavMesh.Raycast (this.transform.position, ray.direction, out nHit, NavMesh.AllAreas);
    if (hasHit) {
        Debug.Log ("Area ID: " + nHit.mask);
        targetPosition = hit.point;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which object is this script attached to?

Comment: It attached to my character.

Comment: The raycast is going out of the camera and you are checking another raycast from player position. If the camera is even slightly away from the character - it can give you totally different hit point.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd argument appears to be incorrect.  The 2nd argument should be the point in which the ray intersected with the object that was clicked on.

Like this:

```
RaycastHit hit;
NavMeshHit nHit;
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)){
    bool hasHit = NavMesh.Raycast (this.transform.position, hit.point, out nHit, NavMesh.AllAreas);
    if (hasHit) {
        Debug.Log ("Area ID: " + nHit.mask);
        targetPosition = hit.point;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working, eve with a simple Debug.DrawLine() the ray starts at the camera Position, and hit the wrong position. Doesn't matter where i click, the Ray hits the same position. So there must be something wrong. And yes, the NavMesh.Raycast must match the Physic Raycast.

Comment: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/NavMesh.Raycast.html
I think that the second parameter is wrong, but if i use the hit.position the raycast show correctly, but doesnt return true.

Comment: It *should* start at the camera position.  The direction should be towards the object that was clicked on.

Comment: oh, you are probably right.

Comment: I updated my answer.  You want to use the point that the ray hit as the 2nd argument and the character(or navAgents)'s position as the 1st argument.

Comment: First param it's ok to be the camera. You was right, the problem it's only the second parameter. It does not work by using the hit.point. The raycast now show correctly by debug.DrawLine(), but return false. It does not hit the NavMesh.

Comment: I Found the problem. I need to use NavMesh.SamplePosition() instead of Raycast()